# High end VPS is Slow

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I have bought a vps to host my website. I have installed apache2, php, mysql server. My vps specs are:

```
ram: 30 gb guaranteed

cpu: 8 cores

ssd: 800 gb

port: 600 Mbps
```

os: Ubuntu 18.04
i have about 500 active users who are watching videos on my android app using my VPS using bandwidth around 200Mbps. Now the problem i m getting is that if I have about 200 users everything working fine response time is great on my app video start immediately but when user reach about 400 video dont even start for a minute what could be the problem.

my ram usage is about 1 gb buff/catche sometime increase to 20gb i don't know how my apache don't even have a cache module.

my apache config is

```
 <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
 StartServers       5
 MinSpareServers    5
 MaxSpareServers    70
 MaxRequestWorker         1000
 MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
 </IfModule>
```

I really can't understand, what could be the problem. Can anyone help me?

ps. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: When it comes to working out why a server is not performing as expected, you’ll need to look at a lot of variables. CPU usage, memory consumption, and storage I/O are usually a good start, but it’s also important to understand exactly how applications impact the system. Have you checked the number of active Apache connections to see if you’ve run out of capacity? `netstat -ant | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d":" -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` will give you a list grouped by IP address to see if something is amiss.